# How to use a custom codec in a Grails unit test

Tags: grails

I am working through a Grails tutorial from InfoQ called Getting Started With Grails, Second Edition, and I am trying to add a custom codec to a unit test. My environment is Grails 1.3.7 and Groovy 1.7.8.

So the codec is SHACodec.groovy, and it lives in grails-app/utils. The contents are:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest 

class SHACodec{ 
  static encode = {target-> 
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance('SHA') 
    md.update(target.getBytes('UTF-8')) 
    return new String(md.digest()).encodeAsBase64()     
  }     
}
```

The codec works just fine when I log into the app. It's being used for a password field in my UserController.authenticate()

```
def authenticate = { 
    def user =  
          User.findByLoginAndPassword(params.login, params.password.encodeAsSHA()) 
        if(user){ 
      session.user = user 
          flash.message = "Hello ${user.login}!" 
      redirect(controller:"race", action:"list")       
        }else{ 
      flash.message = "Sorry, ${params.login}. Please try again." 
          redirect(action:"login") 
    }         
    }
```

When I add this to a unit test, the following error displays:

> No such property: SHACodec for class:
>   racetrack.UserControllerTests
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
>   No such property: SHACodec for class:
>   racetrack.UserControllerTests     at
>   racetrack.UserControllerTests.testAuthenticate(UserControllerTests.groovy:39)

The test is:

```
package racetrack

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.codecs.*
import grails.test.*

class UserControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        String.metaClass.encodeAsSHA = {->  
          SHACodec.encode(delegate) 
        }
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

void testAuthenticate(){ 

  def jdoe = new User(login:"jdoe", password:"password".encodeAsSHA()) 
  mockDomain(User, [jdoe]) 

  controller.params.login = "jdoe" 
  controller.params.password = "password" 
  controller.authenticate() 
  assertNotNull controller.session.user 
  assertEquals "jdoe", controller.session.user.login 

  controller.params.password = "foo" 
  controller.authenticate() 
  assertTrue controller.flash.message.startsWith( 
    "Sorry, jdoe")       
}
```

I found two different recommendations so far. 
First, call the codec directly from the test:

```
SHACodec codec = new SHACodec()
codec.encode("password")
```

Second, use an integration test instead of a unit test.

The results were the same for each option. What is the small thing I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not importing your codec--you are importing the default grails codecs.  You just need to make the import for the codec in the test match the exact package path of where the codec lives.  If you are using an IDE, let it try to import the codec for you...

Comment: Thanks hvgotcodes. So would I create a racetrack directory under grails-app/utils, and add "package racetrack" to the beginning of my codec? I don't have an IDE installed yet, just using a text editor for the time being.

Comment: @benjamindwest, yes, you would have to create the package structure manually.  so something like com/racetrack/security/codecs under the pre-existing grails-app/utils.  Then the package is com.racetrack.security.codecs, and you would import com.racetrack.security.codecs.SHACodec

Answer (score 1):

Use the loadCodec method of the GrailsUnitTestCase. It's very simple. See the example bellow:

```
import grails.test.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.codecs.HTMLCodec

class SomeTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        loadCodec(HTMLCodec)
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testSomething() {
        assertEquals "&lt;p&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;", "<p>Hello World</p>".encodeAsHTML()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @hvgotcodes is correct, but you also need to add the grails-app/utils folder to your Java Build Path before the import works (at least that's what I needed to do with SpringSource Eclipse IDE).